# Hard disk light keeps blinking

Tags: hard-drive, resource-monitor

Who can tell me how to dig into exactly why the hard drive keeps reading/writing? What program is doing that and what is it doing for?

I'm using Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If your are using Windows, SysInternals-Suite brings tools that show you which process ist accessing disks.

Comment: Please review the detailed picture, who can tell me why system.exe is working so hard?http://i62.tinypic.com/2je1n5s.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sysinternals' Process Monitor to track disk activity and you can view my response at [Why is my disk at 99% usage here?](https://superuser.com/questions/747528/why-is-my-disk-at-99-usage-here/748891#748891) to see how.

I think however that the information you have got thorugh Resource Monitor is enough. I can see in the Disk Activity section that you can scroll further to the right. If you do so, you'll be able to see the columns for the number of bytes read and written as well as the total number of bytes. I personally like to view by the total number of bytes and the sort by that heading to see the busiest program.

Once you've found the busiest program the entry under the Image heading will tell you the program that is responsible for all the activity.