# Windows 10 100% disk usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I have Windows 10 on my laptop, and I can't do nearly anything with it because my disk is kept on 100% even when I'm doing nothing.
Some of my observations:

- In most cases, the disk is eaten up by: Windows Antimalvare Executable, |OR| System and Compressed Memory, |OR| svchost
- Every item which were included using only 0.5-3.5 MB/S
- Edit: Now i have 2 min startup 100% then 10-15 min of smooth run, and then again 100%

Tried the followings:

1. Disabled superfetch
2. Disabled Windows searh
3. Disabled all notifications
4. Disabled pagefile
5. Deleted all of theese cloud storage apps

Have no further idea about what should I do. Any other ideas?

Laptop: Asus X555UJ, Intel Core I5 6200U, 5400RPM 500GB HDD, 4GB RAM, Geforce GT 920M
EDIT: I can't do anything because it is so slow, what is slow? everything. Opening up apps, saving documents, even waiting for the start menu to come up.
Edit: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please include your laptop’s specs in the question.

Comment: @DanielB Updated.

Comment: Do you have p2p shut off? Settings-Updates and Security-Advanced Options-Choose How updates are Delivered-**Uncheck** Pcs on my local network and Pcs over the Internet. This could help too.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Helped more or less. Now I have 2-3 min startup 100% then just skpikes. But better, thanks :)
Edit. Getting back, had 10 min smooth run, now again 100%

Comment: @Shapperd can you add a screenshot of your Task manager.

Comment: You really don't describe the problem very well. Why can't you do nearly anything with it? Is it slow? If so, could you describe more specifically what particular things are slow?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Extended, screenshot added

Comment: Well you don’t have a SSD, so the MSI-X problem shouldn’t apply. That being said, the “busy time” is not entirely related to total disk bandwidth but rather how random the accesses are. A regular (5400rpm!) HDD gets saturated a lot sooner (as in several orders of magnitude) than a SSD. So do consider getting a SSD. It will vastly improve your everyday experience. :)

Comment: Have an SSD in main desktop PC, so is it possible, the laptop is just seems to be damn slow after working on SSD, and I'm only Impaitent?

Comment: install a SSD and your issue is gone

Comment: Dont really have budget for that, But I'M thinking about it. :)
@DanielB Problem returned. Didn't change any setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/747528/why-is-my-disk-at-99-usage-here) for Windows 8, because your issue is likely the same even though the OS is different. In short, HDDs score only a few MB/s in random reads/writes or on a fragmented file. Additionally, if your HDD is old and SMART tools e.g. CristalDiskInfo warn you about unstable or remapped sectors, the first noticeable symptom of such aging is also a severe performance drop when such sectors are accessed.

If you can't detect a specific software problem and defragmenting the drive doesn't help, buying a new HDD (or, better yet, an SSD) is the only long-term fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue because of couple of things.

1. I had OneDrive open at 2 locations and I was messing up with folders.
2. I did select all in temp folder and deleted Temp files, but it failed to delete some files.

Then I ran `sfc /scannow` Command prompt by running it as administrator.

This is the result after completing. It may take 10-15 mins to complete.

[image]

After this, disk usage went down to normal.

Answer (score -3):

I can't read the processes in task manager, but I do understand your frustration. I have a laptop with similar specs and the same problem.

In short, the problem is that you probably have a lot of programs and startup services and programs. This will use all of your HDD (hard drive) to read the data and launch the applications. The HDD in your laptop is just slow, and the only thing you can do is do a full (yes full) reset of Windows 10 and ONLY install the bare minimum of applications that you need.

I don't know when you posted this, but I can bet that you never fixed it unless you either upgraded your laptop, got a new laptop or reset Windows 10 (which probably didn't help *that* much).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Actually, this answer isn't helpful and isn't good advice.

Comment: -1. Autostart by definition can only affect the performance at startup, not periodically. Also, no decent HDD can be limited to 3MB/s, meaning there's something else going on.